# changing cards in a card game

Tags: java, bluej

Can anyone help me please? im really stuck trying to make the method changeCard work, everything i try doesnt work. everything else works fine im assuming its something to do with myDeck.shuffleDeck or myDeck.getSuit and myDeck.getCard , its breaking my whole game as the player cant switch his card.

here is my code for the cardClass

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Card
{
// instance variables
public DeckOfCards myDeck;
public int card;
public int suit; 
public String cardName;
public String getSuitName;




public Card()
{
   myDeck = new DeckOfCards();
   myDeck.shuffleDeck();
   card = myDeck.getCard();
   suit = myDeck.getSuit();
   setCardName();

}

public String showCard()
{
   return cardName;
}

public void changeCard()
{

}


public void setCardName()
{
    switch(card)
    {
        case 0:
        cardName = "The Ace of " + getSuitName();
            break;
        case 10: 
        cardName = "The Jack of " + getSuitName();
            break;
        case 11:
        cardName = "The Queen of " + getSuitName();
            break;
        case 12:
        cardName = "The King of " + getSuitName();
            break;
        default:
        cardName =  "The " + card + " Of " + getSuitName();
    }
}

public String getSuitName()
{
       switch(suit)
       {
          case 0 :
          return getSuitName = "Spades";
          case 1 :
          return getSuitName = "Hearts";
          case 2 :
          return getSuitName = "Diamonds";
          case 3 :
          return getSuitName = "Clubs";
          default:
          return "";

        }
 }

 }
```

Comment: Well your `changeCard` method is completely empty at the moment... what is it meant to do, what have you tried, and what happened?

Comment: ive tried putting in 'new card' and ive also tried putting card = myDeck.getCard(); and suit = myDeck.getSuit(); it compiles fine but it never changes the card

Comment: To be honest, I would suggest you get rid of `changeCard` as a method within `Card` anyway. Make your `Card` type immutable, and instead change whatever reference the player has to refer to a different card. We can't really tell enough about what you're doing to give much more information than that though.

Comment: The methods and class designs were set out by my lecturer i cant change them, as you can probably tell i'm very new to programming and im ment to just fill in the gaps without changing the design. Basically the player has 3 cards and should be able to change one of his cards if he wants to so i need a method to change the current card.

Comment: Can you show the code for the DeckOfCards class?